# Retrieving numbers from SQL database with dot instead of comma

Tags: sql, vba, sql-server-2005

I have a macro that extracts information from a SQL server 2005 database. 
Some of this information are numbers... These numbers have the decimal part separated by a comma ",". This is the intended situation. 
But on a certain computer the numbers are retrieved with a dot "." separating the decimal part.

```
Set rs = conn.Execute(".......")
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        RefNum = rs.Fields(0)
    End If
```

How can I change this behaviour? I want the numbers with "," separating the decimal part in all the computers

Comment: Just to clarify, you want all results to be returned with a dot for the decimal place, not a comma?

Comment: I think your 'certain computer' uses another locale which have dot as a decimal separator. Your client code should handle this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood correctly, what you need is the following...

```
Set rs = conn.Execute(".......")
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        RefNum = Replace (rs.Fields(0), ".", ",")
    End If
```

otherwise you can use the Application DecimalSeparator Property

```
 ' Define separators and apply. 
 Application.DecimalSeparator = "." 
 Application.ThousandsSeparator = "" 
 Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
```